# java scanner's same-exact-inputs are not equal (for me?)

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I want to compare three couples of input from `Scanner` (just a quick test)
by using the `Compare` method.

When I run this program, it returns `false` for all three inputs even though there should be a `true` in between. When I remove `Scanner` and put in a `String` myself, I get the correct result

First I thought that it's caused by the extra "Enter" button that stays in the buffer, but when I debugged it, there's nothing unwanted in the buffer
and an extra call for input won't do any help.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

 public class MainSector {
    String Primary, Secondary;

    MainSector(String Primary, String Secondary){
        this.Primary = Primary;
        this.Secondary = Secondary;
    }

MainSector(int Primary, int Secondary) {
    this.Primary = String.valueOf(Primary);
    this.Secondary = String.valueOf(Secondary);
    }

boolean Compare(MainSector x){
    return (x.Primary == Primary && x.Secondary == Secondary );

    }

}


public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner u = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner y = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter String:");
        MainSector Sector1 = new MainSector(u.nextLine(),y.nextLine());

        System.out.println("Enter String:");
        MainSector Sector2 = new MainSector(u.nextLine(),y.nextLine());

        System.out.println("Enter Integer:");
        MainSector Sector3 = new MainSector(u.nextInt(),y.nextInt());


        System.out.println(Sector1.Compare(Sector2));
        System.out.println(Sector1.Compare(Sector3));
        System.out.println(Sector2.Compare(Sector3));


    }
}
```

It returns `false` three times here even if the first two inputs are exactly the same. For example, I get the correct result with this:

```
System.out.println("Enter String:");
MainSector Sector1 = new MainSector("aa","bb");

System.out.println("Enter String:");
MainSector Sector2 = new MainSector("aa","bb");

System.out.println("Enter Integer:");
MainSector Sector3 = new MainSector(45,65);
```

It returns:

`true`

`false`

`false`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem lies in your compare method; using `==` compares reference values. Since you are using different object in your comparisons, they will never have the same reference value in this case. You need to use `.equals(Object)` to compare the exact values. I have edited the code below to reflect this and tested it.

Also, you really don't need 2 scanners to do this, you can use one! As always, please remember to close your scanners; it's good practice.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 



 class MainSector {
    String Primary, Secondary;

    MainSector(String Primary, String Secondary){
        this.Primary = Primary;
        this.Secondary = Secondary;
    }

MainSector(int Primary, int Secondary) {
    this.Primary = Integer.toString(Primary);
    this.Secondary = Integer.toString(Secondary);
    }

//Note the changes made to this method!
    boolean Compare(MainSector x){
        return ((x.Primary.equals(Primary)) && (x.Secondary.equals(Secondary)));

        }
} //End MainSector


public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner u = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter String:");
        MainSector Sector1 = new MainSector(u.nextLine(),u.nextLine());

        System.out.println("Enter String:");
        MainSector Sector2 = new MainSector(u.nextLine(),u.nextLine());

        System.out.println("Enter Integer:");
        MainSector Sector3 = new MainSector(u.nextInt(),u.nextInt());


        System.out.println(Sector1.Compare(Sector2));
        System.out.println(Sector1.Compare(Sector3));
        System.out.println(Sector2.Compare(Sector3));

        u.close();
    } //End main
} //End Test
```

I found a great post, where the answer is explained in extreme detail if you wish to know more: [How do I compare Strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: thanks man, very thorough! but I really have a hard time understanding what part of my program is addressing a "Reference" instead of a "value" and how come replacing the Scanner with actual Strings have changed "Value" to "Reference"

Comment: When you compare addresses, this is known as "by-reference" when you compare the exact data in question; contents of a variable, this is"by-value". So,  when you are doing your compare with == you are comparing the addresses (references) and not the contents (values).